# Why is my scrollTo animation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I'm trying to have a piece of javascript activate when the screen is less than a certain page width. To do this I have added a bit of media query into a script like so:

```
 <script>
    var jmediaquery = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 580px)" );
       if (jmediaquery.matches) {
       $("#navigation a").click(function() {
           var navigationId = $(this).attr("href");
           $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(navigationId).offset().top -60},"slow");
           return false;
       });
    }
</script>
```

However, when i run it the neither the animation works nor the mediaquery works. Why is this?

EDIT: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7wnp/)

To expand on 'not working' the end goal is to have the scrollTo function only work when the screen size is less than the stated width. When above the stated width the function does not apply. My code above seems to disable the animation and works no matter what the screen size.

EDIT 2: Added `("html, body")` as suggested by A.Wolf.

Comment: Perhaps your jmediaquery.matches is empty or null. Can you create a demo on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Also I'd definitely add a `console.log()` to check what that initial offset value is.

Comment: Describe what means not working??? BTW, you should use to handle FF: `$('html, body').animate(...);`   EDIT: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/DrGLd/

Comment: @A.Wolff when I say the animation nor the media query works surely that means that the scroll animation doesn't respond to the media query. No?

Comment: You are not setting media querie, just cheking if media query matches. I'm not sure to understand what you mean... When i ask you to describe what is not working, i mean, e.g: is the click event fired? If no, then you have already your answer below because your posted code is not wrong. PS: of course, if you want to use jQuery, you have to include it: http://jsfiddle.net/c7wnp/2/

Comment: And again, to support FF, you need: `$('html, body').animate(...);`

Comment: @A.Wolff my apologise. Just a bit confused. To clarify the goal.
When a person views the site on a mobile the scroll to function activates. When they view it on a desktop it does not.

Comment: @user2898276 I'm quite sure your code already works (if not testing it on Firefox), just nest code inside document ready handler or set it at the bottom of your page just before `</body>`

Answer (score 4):

Enclose it in a `document.ready()` clause. The control might not have loaded yet.

Alternatively you can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// scroll to error if present
if ($('div.error').length > 0) $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
});
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to add that the code above **assumes** that the error message is at the **bottom** of the page.

Answer (score 0):

may want to run this code when the page is done loading.

```
$(function(){
      /*
        your code here
      */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of all the answers and suggestions which solved my problem. Please note the following is placed at the bottom of the page, just before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $("#navigation a").click(function() {
       var jmediaquery = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 480px)" );
       if (jmediaquery.matches) {
           var navigationId = $(this).attr("href");
           $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(navigationId).offset().top - 20},"slow");
           return false;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   });
</script>
```